# Template specialization of template class member function

Tags: c++, templates, template-specialization

I am trying to specialize template class member functions:

In valueinput.h

```
namespace Gui
    {
    template<class T>
    class ValueInput:public TextInput
        {
        public:         
            static ValueInput* create(Gui& gui_obj,uint32_t style_0,uint32_t style_1
                ,Window* parent,T& obj)
                {return new ValueInput(gui_obj,style_0,style_1,parent,obj);}

            //Polymorphic implementation inherited from
            //TextInput that needs specialization depending on T
            void valueUpdate();

            //Polymorphic implementation inherited from
            //TextInput that needs specialization depending on T
            void displayUpdate();

        protected:
            ValueInput(Gui& gui_obj,uint32_t style_0,uint32_t style_1,Window* parent
                ,T& obj):TextInput(gui_obj,style_0,style_1,parent),ptr_obj(&obj)
                {}

        private:
            T* ptr_obj;
        };
    }
```

In valueinput.cpp

```
template<>
void Gui::ValueInput<double>::displayUpdate()   
    {
    Dialog::messageDisplay(this,{STR("Display Update"),Herbs::LogMessage::Type::INFORMATION},STR("Test"));
    }

template<>
void Gui::ValueInput<double>::valueUpdate() 
    {
    Dialog::messageDisplay(this,{STR("Value Update"),Herbs::LogMessage::Type::INFORMATION},STR("Test"));
    }
```

Compiler output:

```
g++ "valueinput.cpp" -g -municode -Wall -c -std=c++11 -o "__wand_targets_dbg\valueinput.o"
```

> valueinput.cpp:21:45: error: specialization of 'void Gui::ValueInput::displayUpdate() [with T = double]' in different namespace [-fpermissive]
>
> valueinput.cpp:21:6: error:   from definition of 'void Gui::ValueInput::displayUpdate() [with T = double]' [-fpermissive]
>
> valueinput.cpp:27:43: error: specialization of 'void Gui::ValueInput::valueUpdate() [with T = double]' in different namespace [-fpermissive]
>
> valueinput.cpp:27:6: error:   from definition of 'void Gui::ValueInput::valueUpdate() [with T = double]' [-fpermissive]

What is wrong?

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Implementations of explicit specializations can be placed in `cpp` file.

Comment: @Constructor But then they need to appear in the correct namespace though.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ Of course you are right.

Comment: @πάνταῥεῖ I do not really see that this is a duplicate because already knew the answer to the chosen question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rewrite the code in your `valueinput.cpp` file in the following manner:

```
namespace Gui
{
    template<>
    void ValueInput<double>::displayUpdate()   
    {
        Dialog::messageDisplay(this,{STR("Display Update"),Herbs::LogMessage::Type::INFORMATION},STR("Test"));
    }

    template<>
    void ValueInput<double>::valueUpdate() 
    {
        Dialog::messageDisplay(this,{STR("Value Update"),Herbs::LogMessage::Type::INFORMATION},STR("Test"));
    }
}
```

And don't forget to declare these specializations in `valueinput.h` header file if you want to use them outside the `valueinput.cpp` file:

```
namespace Gui
{
    template<class T>
    class ValueInput : public TextInput
    {
        // ...
    };

    template<>
    void ValueInput<double>::displayUpdate();

    template<>
    void ValueInput<double>::valueUpdate();

}
```

**Edit:** I don't know is your variant standard-compliant or not. But here is a small quotation from the standard ([temp.expl.spec] 14.7.3/8):

> A template explicit specialization is in the scope of the namespace in
>   which the template was defined.
>   *[ Example:*
>
> ```
> namespace N {
>   template<class T> class X { /* ... */ };
>   template<class T> class Y { /* ... */ };
>
>   template<> class X<int> { /* ... */ };      // OK: specialization
>                                               // in same namespace
>   template<> class Y<double>;                 // forward declare intent to
>                                               // specialize for double
> }
>
> template<> class N::Y<double> { /* ... */ };  // OK: specialization
>                                               // in same namespace
> ```
>
> *— end example ]*

Unfortunately it is about class template specializations, not about function template specializations or function member specializations of class templates.

Comment: So the compiler cannot understand that Gui is a namespace in this case. Why?

Comment: @user877329 I don't know. But *clang 3.4* [compiles such code](http://rextester.com/MGIAX36625). Possibly it is a bug in *gcc*.

Comment: @user877329 See my addition to the answer with the quotation from the standard which you can be interested in.